# Correct way to push image out of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have been trying to find the answer online but I might be searching for the wrong keywords.

I am trying to understand how to make 2 columns layout with image being full column width and text being in container (hope I am explaining correctly, see image for visuals). I'm looking for the clean way to do this that would match margins of my other containers.[image: See image to understand better]

Would anyone be able to help me understand how to make this work with HTML and CSS.

I tried making two columns and then adding padding to the text column which does not match my other containers.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to show some code. Also, please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: It's simply a matter of putting your image on an outer element as a background. There's heaps of information on this here and on MDN.